# How to prove that $A \bigwedge ( \bigvee_{1< i <\infty} C_i) \equiv \bigvee_{1<i<\infty}(A\bigwedge C_i) $?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that $A , C_i$ are propositional formulas ( or for simplifications , variables ) for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$ , 
How to prove that  $A \bigwedge ( \bigvee_{1 \leqslant
  i <\infty} C_i) \equiv
 \bigvee_{1 \leqslant
i<\infty}(A\bigwedge C_i) $ ?

Of course $\bigvee$ is ***disjunction*** and $\bigwedge$ is ***conjunction*** .

I can prove this statement If $i$ ranges from $1$ to some finite *natural number*  $n$ using induction. but when $i$ ranges from $1$ to infinity , I have no idea of how to prove this!

Comment: Most likely when you used mathematical induction you proved it with $n \to \infty$, not just a finite $n$. But anyway, you can show us your proof, so it's more clear.

Comment: @DanielFischer , Oh yeah , you are right , I have fixed the code now , thanx for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kaster , when n approaches infinity , the length of the Disjunctions still finite , but my formula has infinite length! they are different cases .

Comment: @DanielFischer , thanx again for pointing this out :) but there is a tiny mistake in the title , as I wrote $<$ not $\leqslant$ and the reason is that this make the title longer than allowed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $A \bigwedge ( \bigvee_{1 \leqslant i <\infty} C_i)$ and $ \bigvee_{1 \leqslant i<\infty}(A\bigwedge C_i)$ are not propositional formulas anymore, because of the infinite disjunction.

So, it's actually $A \land \exists i \in {\mathbb N}.C_i \iff \exists i \in {\mathbb N}. A \land C_i$.

To prove this: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A \land \exists i \in {\mathbb N}.C_i$. Then $A$ and $\exists i \in {\mathbb N}.C_i$. Take $i_0 \in {\mathbb N}$ such that $C_{i_0}$. Then also $A \land C_{i_0}$ and therefore $\exists i \in {\mathbb N}. A \land C_i$. ($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $\exists i \in {\mathbb N}. A \land C_i$. Take $i_0 \in {\mathbb N}$ such that $A \land C_{i_0}$. Then $A$ and $C_{i_0}$. So therefore $\exists i \in {\mathbb N}.C_i$ and also $A \land \exists i \in {\mathbb N}.C_i$.